# Set Another Column Grid Height To Match Another Column

Tags: javascript, css

I have:

HTML:

```
<main>
  <section id="category">
    <div class="icon">About</div>
    ...
  </section>
  <section id="about">
    <article id="about_info"></article>
    ...
  </section>
</main>
```

It's CSS:

```
main {
  grid-template   :
                      [category-start about-start] "category about"       auto     [about-end]
                      [other-start] "..." [category-end other-end]
                      / 20% auto;
  gap             :   .5em 0;
  margin          :   0;
}

main #category {
  grid-template-row : var(--about-content-height) auto 5%;
}
```

I will set `--about-content-height` dynamically as the height is changing according to whether current view is in grid mode or carousel mode, with:

```
const main        = document.getElementsByTagName("main");
const mainStyle   = getComputedStyle(Array.from(main)[0]);
const mainHeight  = mainStyle.height.slice(0, mainStyle.height.length - 2);
const about       = document.getElementById("about");
const aboutHeight = about.clientHeight;

const height      = Math.round(about / mainHeight * 100);

document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--about-content-height', `${height}%`);
```

My issue lies in the line:

```
const mainStyle   = getComputedStyle(Array.from(main)[0]);
```

and

```
const mainHeight  = mainStyle.height.slice(0, mainStyle.height.length - 2);
```

There is difference between `console.log(mainStyle)` and `console.log(mainStyle.height)`.
The correct one was within `mainStyle` by itself. But it's value started to be different in `mainStyle.height`.

Here're the values of both the console:
[image: mainStyle by itself]
[image: mainStyle.height]

Why is there a difference between them?

## Update

So it basically is the difference between loading of the content.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.myFunction();
}, 300);
```

will give me the right height. `window.onload` or `readyState === "complete"` doesn't do anything.

## Edit

Is there any way to not use the `setTimeout` but to relies on the DOM finishing whatever is happening on it?

Thanks for your answer in advance.